# What can be said about $p\in Spec(R)$ when $R_p$ is a field?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

What can be said about $p\in Spec(R)$ when $R_p$ is a field? Especially when $R$ is local noetherian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obviously $p$ must be a minimal prime, in other words have height zero.
But minimality is not sufficient  : if $k$ is a field and $R=k[\epsilon]=k[t]/(T^2)$, the ideal $p=(\epsilon )$ is minimal but $R_p=R$ is not a field.

However if $R$ is reduced and $p$ is a minimal prime, then $R_p$ is reduced (as a localization of a reduced ring) and $pR_p\subset R_p$ is the only prime ideal of $R_p$.
It is thus zero since it equals the nilradical of the reduced ring $R_p$, and so $R_p$ is a domain.
But a domain of dimension zero is a field, since the prime  $(0)$ is maximal by zero-dimensionality.
We have thus proved :

**Proposition:**
In a reduced ring $R$ the localization $R_p$ of $R$ at a prime is a field if and only if $p$ is a minimal prime.